# Delete row if table exists

Tags: query, delete, sql-standard

I want to delete a row from a table *if that table exists*.

Below is the delete statement

```
DELETE 
FROM UM_CLAIM_BEHAVIOR 
WHERE UM_TENANT_ID = ?
```

Can I extend this query to check the existence of the table or is there any other alternative to check existence of table before executing delete query?

According to comments it is not possible to give a platform-independent solution for this.

Comment: Why not just run the delete and catch any error in your application? There is generic solution to this.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: thanks. I will try that way. catching and continue seems like a good solution.

Answer (score 4):

In SQL Server you could do something like this

```
IF EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM sys.objects AS o
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
            ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id
        WHERE CONCAT (s.NAME, '.', o.NAME) = 'dbo.UM_CLAIM_BEHAVIOR'
            AND o.type_desc = 'USER_TABLE'
        )
BEGIN
    DELETE T
    FROM UM_CLAIM_BEHAVIOR AS T
    WHERE UM_TENANT_ID = ?
END
```

Comment: thanks. but I searched for a platform independent one

Comment: @lakshman: there is no "platform" independent way to do this. SQL Server is about the only DBMS where you can mix procedural code and "regualar" SQL code like that. For nearly every other DBMS you will need to write a stored procedure to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a platform-independant method, you just have to make a round trip to the server.

```
SELECT 'DELETE FROM ' || t.table || ' WHERE WHATEVER;'
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name = 'mytable';
```

Now you execute the whatever that returns. If the table exists, it'll return the query to delete the row. If not, it'll return NULL.